# Numpy-vectorized function to repeat blocks of consecutive elements

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, vectorization

Numpy has а [repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) function, that repeats each element of the array a given (per element) number of times.

I want to implement a function that does similar thing but repeats not individual elements, but variably sized blocks of consecutive elements. Essentially I want the following function:

```
import numpy as np

def repeat_blocks(a, sizes, repeats):
    b = []    
    start = 0
    for i, size in enumerate(sizes):
        end = start + size
        b.extend([a[start:end]] * repeats[i])
        start = end
    return np.concatenate(b)
```

For example, given

```
a = np.arange(20)
sizes = np.array([3, 5, 2, 6, 4])
repeats = np.array([2, 3, 2, 1, 3])
```

then

```
repeat_blocks(a, sizes, repeats)
```

returns

```
array([ 0,  1,  2, 
        0,  1,  2,

        3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 
        3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 
        3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 

        8,  9, 
        8,  9,

        10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,

        16, 17, 18, 19,
        16, 17, 18, 19,
        16, 17, 18, 19 ])
```

I want to push these loops into numpy in the name of performance. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach using `cumsum` -

```
# Get repeats for each group using group lengths/sizes
r1 = np.repeat(np.arange(len(sizes)), repeats)

# Get total size of output array, as needed to initialize output indexing array
N = (sizes*repeats).sum() # or np.dot(sizes, repeats)

# Initialize indexing array with ones as we need to setup incremental indexing
# within each group when cumulatively summed at the final stage. 
# Two steps here:
# 1. Within each group, we have multiple sequences, so setup the offsetting
# at each sequence lengths by the seq. lengths preceeeding those.
id_ar = np.ones(N, dtype=int)
id_ar[0] = 0
insert_index = sizes[r1[:-1]].cumsum()
insert_val = (1-sizes)[r1[:-1]]

# 2. For each group, make sure the indexing starts from the next group's
# first element. So, simply assign 1s there.
insert_val[r1[1:] != r1[:-1]] = 1

# Assign index-offseting values
id_ar[insert_index] = insert_val

# Finally index into input array for the group repeated o/p
out = a[id_ar.cumsum()]
```

Comment: `(sizes*repeats).sum()` is better done as `np.dot(sizes, repeats)` if the arrays may be large.

Comment: Could you explain the idea behind this?

Comment: @yurikilochek Added some comments.

Answer (score 3):

This function is a great candidate to speed up using Numba:

```
@numba.njit
def repeat_blocks_jit(a, sizes, repeats):
    out = np.empty((sizes * repeats).sum(), a.dtype)
    start = 0
    oi = 0
    for i, size in enumerate(sizes):
        end = start + size
        for rep in range(repeats[i]):
            oe = oi + size
            out[oi:oe] = a[start:end]
            oi = oe
        start = end
    return out
```

This is significantly faster than Divakar's pure NumPy solution, and a lot closer to your original code.  I made no effort at all to optimize it.  Note that `np.dot()` and `np.repeat()` can't be used here, but that doesn't matter when all the code gets compiled.

Plus, since it is `njit` meaning "nopython" mode, you can even use `@numba.njit(nogil=True)` and get multicore speedup if you have many of these calls to make.

Comment: Can you please provide a speed up test?

Comment: @anishtain4: Depends on the data size.  For the tiny input in the question, the difference is more than 10x, but for larger inputs the speedup is more like 1.5x.