# How to repeat rows and maintaining order in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

The idea is to repeat an array for a number of times. The below should do

```
import numpy as np

rpt=np.repeat(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), repeats=3, axis=0)
```

the code above will produce an array of

```
1 2
1 2
1 2
3 4
3 4
3 4
```

But, I would like to maintain the order as below,

```
1 2
3 4
1 2
3 4
1 2
3 4
```

May I know which setting to set to achieve the above output?

Comment: To extend existent quite basic solutions (`np.vstack` and `np.tile`) you might like to read more about how to repeat blocks of [any size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154989/). Something like `repeat_extension([1,2,3,4], blocks=[4], repeats=[3]).reshape(-1, 2)`

Comment: If the arrray was (1,2,2) shape your repeat would create the desired blocks.  Then reshape the (3,2,2)) to (6,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `vstack`:

```
np.vstack([a]*3)
```

Another is `tile`:

```
np.tile(a,(3,1))
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.tile`

```py
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

In [7]: np.tile(a,(2,1))
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [9]: np.tile(a,(3,1))
Out[9]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```