# Python make each matrix in a list to same size

Tags: python, numpy

Assume multiple matrices with different amount of rows. They are contained in a list. How can I fill the rows of the smaller matrices, so that they have the same size as the biggest matrix ?

```
list_of_matrices = []
list_of_matrices.append(np.array([[3,3],[4,4]]))
list_of_matrices.append(np.array([[1,1,3],[2,2,5]]))
list_of_matrices.append(np.array([[1,1,3,7],[2,2,5,9]]))
```

From list_of_matrices I want to create a 3D numpy array of e.g. shape 3x4x2 where the missing values (because the first to 2D matrices are too small) are filled with a scalar value (more specific the mean of each matrix around axis 1). I want to do that in a performant way (no for loops).

Comment: Your arrays are not balanced in size which means you can't concatenate them or, you should contatenate arrays that are padded with zeros at least. Also every item requires some kind of looping if they have different shapes.

Comment: How can I pad this list with certain values so they all have the same shape? I have nothing against some kind of looping (if it is efficient such as a numpy function), I just want to avoid for-loops

Answer (score 0):

I tried various ways and concluded this should be readable and quite efficient:

```
z = np.zeros((3, 2, 4), dtype=int)
for i, n in enumerate(list_of_matrices):
    z[i, :n.shape[0], :n.shape[1]] = n
```

While trying to find any other method than looping I concluded that every list of `list_of_matrices` has unbalanced amounts of cells to be assigned to `z` so even the most clever ways requires nothing better than concatenation of these groups which is slow in `numpy`.

This is an example of concatenation of index groups:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
b = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
c = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
z[a, b, c] = np.concatenate([n.ravel() for n in list_of_matrices])
```

It also requires `np.concatenate` and list comprehension therefore efficiency is also lost here. But if you really need to optimise it further, you can try replace concatenation like so:

```
# Use list of lists instead because arrays are slow while iterating 
list_of_matrices = [[[3,3],[4,4]], [[1,1,3],[2,2,5]], [[1,1,3,7],[2,2,5,9]]]
from itertools import chain
concatenation = list(chain(*list(chain(*list_of_matrices))))
```

and create abovementioned sequences of indexes `a`, `b`, `c` applying tricks of [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) + [repetition of specific blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154989/)