# Sort array with repeated values

Tags: python, numpy

I have to order an array with values from 0 to 9 that are repeated and obtain the vector initial index. The input array is:

`[3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 0, 9, 5, 3, 9, 2, 7, 6, 4]`

I would like to obtain the following order:

`array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9], dtype=uint8)`

Instead of:

`array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9])`

which is given by:

```
import numpy as np
a = [3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 0, 9, 5, 3, 9, 2, 7, 6, 4]
np.argsort(a)
```

Is there a way to manipulate this function?

Comment: Do all numbers always have the same count ? 0-9 each appears twice in the input ?

Comment: Why did you delete the old version of the question, re-ask it, and still not address any of the clarifying questions I asked you about?

Comment: Your definition of order, in this case, is not well defined. In case you don't have the same number of duplicates for each element, what do you expect to get?

Comment: Let me try again: if `a` is instead `[1,1,4,4,2,3]`, what should the result be, and why?

Comment: In case a is [1,1,4,4,2,3] I need the index of a that corresponds to [1,2,3,4,1,4]

Comment: This is actually a pretty interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,3,5]
l_oredered = []
while len(l) != 0:
    unique_nums = list(set(l))
    unique_nums.sort()
    l_oredered.extend(unique_nums)
    for num in unique_nums:
        l.remove(num)

print(l_oredered)
```

This will result with:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can apply the thinking with NumPy or convert the final result into a NumPy array.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting task! Here is my attempt at to solve the problem

```py
import numpy as np


def groupsort(a: np.ndarray):
    uniques, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
    min_count = np.min(counts)
    counts -= min_count
    n_easy = min_count * len(uniques)

    # Pre allocate array
    values = np.empty(n_easy + counts.sum(), dtype=a.dtype)

    # Set easy values
    temp = values[:n_easy].reshape(min_count, len(uniques))
    temp[:] = uniques

    # Set hard values
    i = n_easy
    while np.any(mask := counts > 0): # Python 3.8 syntax
        masksum = mask.sum()
        values[i : i + masksum] = uniques[mask]
        counts -= mask
        i += masksum
    return values


a = np.array(list(range(4)) * 2 + [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1])
np.random.shuffle(a)
print(a)
# [3 0 1 0 1 0 2 1 2 1 0 2 1 1 2 0 3 1]
print(groupsort(a))
# [0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 1 1]

# Your input
a = np.array([3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 0, 9, 5, 3, 9, 2, 7, 6, 4])
print(groupsort(a))
# [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9]
```

The idea is to split the problem in two cases. One easy case and one hard case.  The easy case is to handle inputs like this: `a = [0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3]`, where the counts for each unique value are equal. Then you can simply count the number `n` of a specific value (e.g. 0), then just do `list(range(max(a))) * n`.

The hard case is to handle inputs such as `a = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,2]`. Then the idea is to get the counts of each value, in this case `counts = [3,5,2,0]`. Then do:

```
values = np.empty(counts.sum())
i = 0
while np.any(mask := counts > 0): # Python 3.8 syntax
    masksum = mask.sum()
    values[i : i + masksum] = uniques[mask]
    counts -= mask
    i += masksum
```

In my solution you see I have combined the two solutions to optimize for speed. Assuming `np.unique` has a linear average time complexity, then this algorithm also has a linear average runtime complexity.

Answer (score 0):

For an array with a small number of elements @Mr.O's answer is faster.  The code below is faster if there are more than around 100 ints in arr.

```
import numpy as np

def sort_groups( arr ):
    ct = np.ones( len(arr), dtype = np.int64 )
    for i in set( arr ):
        ct[arr == i] = ct[arr == i ].cumsum()
    # ct calculates a rank for each int in arr
    tosort = ( arr.max() + 1 ) * ct + arr 
    # tosort ranks by ct first then a if ct's are equal
    return arr[ np.argsort( tosort ) ]
     
a = np.array([3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 0, 9, 5, 3, 9, 2, 7, 6, 4])
sort_groups( a )
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9])
```

Breaking the function out to see what's happening:

```
arr = a

ct = np.ones( len(arr), dtype = np.int64 )
for i in set( arr ):
    ct[arr == i] = ct[arr == i ].cumsum()

arr, ct
# (array([3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 0, 9, 5, 3, 9, 2, 7, 6, 4]),
#  array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]))

tosort = ( arr.max() + 1 ) * ct + arr  # Assumes arr is > 0

tosort
# array([13, 11, 12, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17, 21, 20, 19, 25, 23, 29, 22, 27, 26, 24])

arr[ np.argsort( tosort ) ]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 2-liner:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
b = [x for y in [[u for i, u in enumerate(unique) if counts[i] > n] for n in range(counts.max())] for x in y]
```

Output:

```
>>> b
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 1, 5, 9]
#^ reset                    ^ reset                    ^ reset
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `np.bincount` instead of `np.unique`, `np.sort` or `np.argsort` because it's much faster in cases maximum item of data is small.

```
def count_out(arr, N):
    bins = np.bincount(arr, minlength=N) 
    threshold_idx = np.unique(bins[bins!=0]) 
    counts = np.diff(threshold_idx, prepend=0)
    mask = (bins >= threshold_idx[:, None])
    full_mask = np.repeat(mask, counts, axis=0)
    blocks = np.repeat([np.arange(N)], np.sum(counts), axis=0)
    return blocks[full_mask]

N = 10
X = np.array([3, 5, 3, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 6, 8, 8, 7, 0, 5, 9, 7, 8, 1, 5, 8, 8, 1, 0, 7, 1, 9])
print(X)
print(count_out(X, N))
>>> [3 5 1 3 9 7 5 9 0 9 9 0 0 6 8 8 8 9 7 0 5 9 7 8 3 1 5 8 8 1 0 7 1 9 9 8]
>>> [0 1 3 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 3 5 7 8 9 0 1 3 5 7 8 9 0 1 5 7 8 9 0 8 9 8 9 8 9 9]
```

The key idea is to find `counts` of how many times does each block repeat. Then create unique mask for each block:

Blocks:

```
[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]
```

Unique masks:

```
[[1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

Finally, reconstruct all the masks by the `counts` we've got.

Counts: `[1 2 1 1 2 1]`

Full masks:

```
[[1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

By the way, it seems this can be optimised further. At first, creation of repetitive blocks is redundant since there should be a way to create a pointer to one single block. Secondly, it's slow in case full mask is sparse. In this case you should consider implementing [your own way to repeat blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154989/numpy-vectorized-function-to-repeat-blocks-of-consecutive-elements?rq=1) with no masking.

I hope it's helpful for you at the current point.

Answer (score -1):

IIUC, you want to have a duplicated, sorted, array.

Remove the duplicated values using `numpy.unique`, sort, and `tile` to the expected size:

```
a = np.array([3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 0, 9, 5, 3, 9, 2, 7, 6, 4])
b = np.unique(a)
b = np.tile(b, len(a)//len(b))
```

output:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9])
```

Comment: This was elegant! I would like to add that `np.unique` actually sorts the unique values (it is specified in the docs). Making the `sorted` redundant.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem according to the comments / answers under the original post. There the OP answers that `[1,1,4,4,2,3]` should equal to `[1,2,3,4,1,4]`. That doesn't seem to be the case with your code.

Comment: @HampusLarsson I had not seen this

Comment: Thank for the answer, I need the information about the initial vector index that corresponds to [3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 0, 9, 5, 3, 9, 2, 7, 6, 4].